# Unable to install SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server

When I'm trying to install `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU` i got following error.

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:    
There was an error generating the XML document.    
Error code 0x84B10001
```

What is the reason for this?

**EDIT:** I tried to install SQL 2008. even though i got same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an access denied error. It means the user performing the installation doesn't have the necessary rights. Several users have found success creating a new user, configuring them as a local administrator, and then running the installation logged in as this user.

More Info: [http://geekswithblogs.net/vitus/archive/2009/09/26/workaround-for-sql-2008-express-installation-error-0x84b10001.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926114646/http://geekswithblogs.net/vitus/archive/2009/09/26/workaround-for-sql-2008-express-installation-error-0x84b10001.aspx)

Comment: thank you .. you are correct problem with access rights.. thanks again

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have just had this issue trying to install SQL2014

Comment: This problem also occurs in SQL2017, and this also solves it. I've checked the pre-installation requirements and can't find any explicit reason why this would happen, so the documentation is lacking. My initial admin user was a domain user, not a local one; I'm guessing that's causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to re-installed it properly follow these [**instructions**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23878.installing-sql-server-2014-step-by-step-tutorial.aspx)

Comment: Too generic answer. What made you assume OP did not follow the instructions? What specific part of the instructions might have prevented the issue?